# Updating a column according to values of another column

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a table named **MAINTABLE**  and columns **score**  , **grade** . I'm populating **score** from user input, while the contents of **grade** depends on the value of **score**. In that

```
if score >= 70
then grade is 'A'
if score >= 60 AND <70
then grade is 'B'
if score >= 50 AND <60
then grade is 'C'
if score >= 45 AND <50
then grade is 'D'
if score >= 40 AND <45
then grade is 'E'
else grade is 'F'
```

Please how can i write an update statement for this type of problem?

Thanks for your help. I most appreciate it.
Thank you

**UPDATE:**    **This what i tried**

```
 $query = mysql_query(UPDATE maintable

    SET grade = CASE

    WHEN score >= 70 THEN 'A'

    WHEN score >= 60 THEN 'B'

    WHEN score >= 50 THEN 'C'

    WHEN score >= 40 THEN 'D'

    WHEN score >= 30 THEN 'E'

    ELSE 'F'

     END") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself first?

Comment: Write "END" at the end of your sql statement.
Your values are different in the pseudo code and the sql statement btw.

Comment: @leif  
thanks.....
i'm still getting this same error. You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN score >=70 THEN 'A'' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using case statements in your query here is the documentation of case statements:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: This isnt working.

    UPDATE maintable

    SET grade = CASE

        WHEN score >= 70 THEN 'A'

        WHEN score >= 60 THEN 'B'

        WHEN score >= 50 THEN 'C'

        WHEN score >= 40 THEN 'D'

        WHEN score >= 30 THEN 'E'

        ELSE 'F'

Comment: it says error around 'CASE WHEN score >= 70 THEN 'A'' at line 2

Comment: use the end statement after else statement

Comment: i'm still getting this same error. You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN score >=70 THEN 'A'' at line 2

Comment: use statement END; like this dont use '' after end

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if it still does not work with CASE for you, then you could try doing it with WHERE.

```
UPDATE maintable SET grade = 'A' WHERE score >= 70;
UPDATE maintable SET grade = 'B' WHERE score >= 60 AND score < 70;
```

... and so on.
You could also use BETWEEN, I guess (I don't work with mysql and can't test it here).

Answer (score 0):

Do not write update statement, keep your table normalized.
Calculate your grade letter at select time. This is how databases works.

Select your $score from the table and then in PHP

```
$grades = array('A' => 70, 'B' => 60, 'C' => 50, 'D' => 45, 'E' => 40, 'F' => 0);
foreach ($grades as $grade => $value) {
  if ($score >= $value) {
    break;
  }
}
```

so you will have your grade letter in the `$grade` variable.

Comment: thanks for the advice.. Please how can i write this? Thank you Sir.